# Django Rest Framework object has no attribute pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working in Django / DjangoRestFramework trying to use extra actions to build out a foreignkey that is routable.  I am getting the following error, I believe it has something to do with the create method on the `FinancialsSerializer`, or lack thereof, but I am not sure

```
web_1  | AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

stocks.viewset

```
   19 class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   20     queryset = Stock.objects.all()
   21     serializer_class = StockSerializer
   22     lookup_url_kwarg = "ticker"
   23     lookup_field = "ticker__iexact"
   24
   25     @action(detail=True, methods=["POST", "GET"])
   26     def financials(self, request, ticker=None):
   27         if request.method == "GET":
   28             stock = self.get_object()
   29             financials = stock.get_financials()
   30             financials = FinancialsSerializer(financials)
   31             return Response(financials.data)
   32         if request.method == "POST":
   33             serializer = FinancialsSerializer(request.data)
   34             financials = Financials.objects.create(serializer.data)
   35             financials.save()
```

FinancialsSerializer

```
  9 class FinancialsSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
 10     balance_sheet = BalanceSheetSerializer()
 11     income_statement = IncomeStatementSerializer()
 12     cashflows_statement = CashflowsStatementSerializer()
 13
 14     class Meta:
 15         model = Financials
 16         fields = ["balance_sheet", "income_statement", "cashflows_statement"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in your code.

First, for `GET` method:

```py
serializer = FinancialsSerializer(financials, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Second, for `POST` method:

```py
serializer = FinancialsSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: when posting some data I now get a 200 status code instead of 201.  its not creating the object for me

Comment: Change it to `return Response(serializer.data, status=201)`. Status code `200` doesn't mean that object wasn't created. If that's the only reason why you think it wasn't created

Comment: checked in the db and the object isn't created . . . the financials is a foreign key to the stock object, could that be why ?